# Canon 80D or Nikon D7500 for travel photography

Tags: lens, canon, nikon, portrait, landscape

I have a trip coming up, which will involve me shooting landscapes and portraits, so I'd bring a superzoom and a portrait lens)

I have a Canon 80D (with a Sigma 18-250mm and a 50mm f1.8) and a Nikon D7500, (with a Tamron 18-200mm and a Tokina 100m f2.8 [but it may be too close for portraits])

Any idea on what camera should I take along? I would also like to consider the performance of the camera (i.e. dynamic range, colour etc.) but it's quite hard weighing the pros and cons of both.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the day, it's really up to you and your shooting style - and no one can tell you that.

You've got huge zooms for both, but more reach with the Canon set up. For primes, you've got more aperture with the Canon set up.

Yes, I'm focusing on the lenses and you asked about the bodies. This is because IMO, the body doesn't matter as much. We always tell amateurs, spend your money on glass.

And in your case, your Canon glass gives you more reach on the telephoto end, and a faster prime for when the light gets low.

If it were me, I'd go with the Canon set up for those reason alone.

Answer (score -3):

Take the 80D.  If it is a paid portrait trip, then you might consider something else altogether, like a 6D Mark II.  And then you have the 80D as your backup camera.  That way your batteries interchange and is a "true" backup.

Comment: Wow. It's half tempting to keep the -1 for that comment alone. the 80D is not implied to be a vlogging camera. It's Canon's current midrange DSLR... Canon has been offering flip screens on all their lower end cameras since the 600D in 2011. If it was intended just for vlogging it wouldn't offer features such as 24MP, 45point AF, 7FPS or a view finder... things used primarily for stills.

Comment: So, with the edit, this answer doesn't give any reasoning at all. A coin flip would do the same....